# Primefaces Block UI doesn´t work while jasperreports' report is generated.

Tags: primefaces, jasper-reports, blockui

Greetings form South America. I'm generating a report (using jasper reports), so while this proccess occurs I want to block the page showing an appropriate message. The report works **perfectly** firing the action with the following line of code:

```
<p:commandButton id="pago" actionListener="#{transaccionBncController.reporteGeneral}" value="Reporte General " ajax="false"/>
```

**NOTE**: to use the ajax="false" attribute is obligatory, or everything goes bad, and generate the report is imposible!

Now, When I try to add the Primefaces blockUI componet in order to block the page and show an appropiate message (while the report is generated), I´m using the following code:

```
<p:blockUI block="panelGrid" trigger="pago">
 Generando Reporte...<br />  
 <h:graphicImage library="images" name="ajaxloading.gif"/> 
</p:blockUI>
```

the blockUI componet works well, but the report doesn't works anymore. 
I've tried everything, and the problem always is the same about the ajax="false" attribute and blocking the page.

The Following is the entire souce on which I'm workin on:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                template="/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content" >
        <fieldset id="fieldsetgenerico" >
            <legend> Reporte General </legend>
            <h:form id="formreporte">
                <p:growl autoUpdate="true" life="3000"  id="growl" />  
                <h:panelGrid columns="3" id="panelGrid" >

                    <h:outputLabel value="Fecha inicial: " for="fechaInicial" /> 
                    <p:calendar id="fechaInicial" value="#   {transaccionBncController.fechaInicial}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"  locale="es" required="true" requiredMessage="Fecha Inicial Requerida" navigator="true" effect="fadeIn" effectDuration="100"/>

                    <h:outputLabel value="" /> 

                    <h:outputLabel value="Fecha Final: " for="fechaFinal"/>
                    <p:calendar id="fechaFinal" value="# {transaccionBncController.fechaFinal}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" locale="es" required="true" requiredMessage="Fecha Final Requerida" navigator="true" effect="fadeIn" effectDuration="300"/>

                    <p:tooltip for="fechaFinal" value="Campo Requerido. No puede ser anterior a la Fecha Inicial" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip" />

                    <h:outputLabel value="Estado: " for="estado"  />     
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="estado" value="#{transaccionBncController.estTra}"  >                                       
                        <f:selectItems value="#{estadoTransaccionBncController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"  />                                    
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                    <h:outputLabel value="" />

                    <h:outputLabel value="Tipo Transaccion: " for="tipoTransaccion"/>
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="tipoTransaccion" value="#{transaccionBncController.tipTra}"  
                                     valueChangeListener="#{transaccionBncController.defineTipoTransaccion}"  >
                        <f:selectItems value="#{tipoTransaccionBncController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"/>
                        <f:ajax  execute="@all" render="panelGrid1" immediate="true"></f:ajax>     
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                    <h:outputLabel value="" />

                    <h:outputLabel value="Entidad Financiera: " for="entidadFinanciera"  />                               
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="entidadFinanciera" value="#{transaccionBncController.cliente}" 
                                     valueChangeListener="#{transaccionBncController.actualizaAgencias}" >  
                        <f:selectItems value="#{clienteBncController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"/>  
                        <f:ajax  execute="@form" render="panelGrid" ></f:ajax> 
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                    <h:outputLabel value="" /> 

                    <h:outputLabel value="Agencia: " for="agencia"  />
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="agencia" value="#{transaccionBncController.ag}"  >
                        <f:selectItems value="#{transaccionBncController.itemsAvailableSelectOneAgencia}"/>                 
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                    <h:outputLabel value="" /> 

                    <h:outputLabel value="Código Financiero: " for="codFinanciero"  />
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="codFinanciero" value="#{transaccionBncController.codigoFinanciero}"   >
                        <f:selectItems value="#{productoBncController.itemsAvailableSelectOneC}"/>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                    <h:outputLabel value="" />

                </h:panelGrid>           
                <br/>               
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="panelGrid1">   
                    <p:commandButton id="pago" icon="ui-icon-check"  actionListener="#{transaccionBncController.reporteGeneral}" value="Reporte General " rendered="#{transaccionBncController.tipTransaccion != 'ANULACION' }" update="growl" style="margin:0" /> 
                    <p:blockUI block="panelGrid" trigger="pago"  >
                        Generando Reporte<br />  
                        <h:graphicImage library="images" name="ajaxloading.gif"/> 
                    </p:blockUI>    
                </h:panelGrid>      
            </h:form>
        </fieldset>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>

</html>
```

I supose the root cause of this problem is the ajax interaction, because generating report (wihtout the blockui code) works amazing. this is my source code from which I'm getting reports:

```
public void reporteGeneral(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws JRException, IOException, SQLException {


        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@170.25.18.38:1521:xxx", "xxx", "xxx");

        Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        parametros.put("fechaInicial", fInicial);
        parametros.put("fechaFinal", fFinal);
        parametros.put("query", query);


        String reportPath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/reportes/report4.jasper");
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportPath, parametros, conn);


        //jasperPrint=JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportPath, new HashMap(),conn); 


        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();

        java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String fi = sdf.format(fInicial);
        String ff = sdf.format(fFinal);

        String fecha = fi.toString() + "_" + ff.toString();

        httpServletResponse.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=reporte_" + fecha + ".pdf");
        ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();

        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, servletOutputStream);

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
}
```

Thank you so much guys. Excuse me if the question is so newbie, but I think is a good chance to learn, because I didn't find something about this topic on internet. 
Again, thanks a lot for your help.
Santiago